# Build sequence of dates in the environment

Tags: r

I want to create a sequence of dates starting from a day to the current date. So I came up with this code
start <- as.Date("01-08-14",format="%d-%m-%y")
end   <- Sys.Date()

```
theDate <- start

while (theDate > end)
{
print(paste0(format(theDate,"%d%b%y")))
theDate <- theDate + 1                    
}
TheDate<-data.frame(theDate)
```

Unfortunately, all the data is loaded in the console, not the environment where I want it to be. Can you help me? I want this because I calculated the returns of apple in this way

```
apple<-getSymbols("AAPL",  auto.assign = F, from="2000-01-01")

Rets<-dailyReturn(apple,subset=NULL,"continuous")

APPLE.prices<- Ad(getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = F, from = Sys.Date() - 190, to = 
Sys.Date()))
APPLE.rets<-dailyReturn(APPLE.prices)
```

And even if there are the dates following the returns on the data produced it is not shown in Shiny. Can you please help me with the first quest and enlighten me with another option that uses the already indicated dates in the returns dataframe?

Comment: You can use `seq` to create sequences of dates, e.g., `x <- seq(from = start, to = end, by = "1 day")`

Comment: It sounds like this is inside a Shiny app. Environments in Shiny are a little more complicated than normal. How to get this object in the right environment will depend on where the code is run: is it part of the set-up of the app? Or is in a reactive expression? Or in an observer? Somewhere else?

Comment: I'm also confused why you need this date vector at all... doesn't `getSymbols` include the dates? As row names or something? [This blog post](https://medium.com/financial-data-analysis/using-getsymbols-to-load-financial-data-r-5c3328e802b1) has code to make a nice data frame from `getSymbols`.

Comment: It should but it doesn't  show em as output. Can I share with you my code?

Comment: Yes it is inside Shiny app